# Does Spark Structured Streaming maintain the order of Kafka messages?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming application that consumes messages from multiple Kafka topics and writes the results to another Kafka topic. To maintain the integrity of the data, it's imperative that the order of messages in source partitions is maintained. So if message `A` precedes message `B` in a partition, `processed(A)` should be written to the output topic before `processed(B)` (processed A and B will go to the same partition too as the same hash string is used).

Does Spark Structured Streaming guarantee this?

Comment: Order is guaranteed within the partition. So, going by your example, A will be processed before B if they are consumed from the same Kafka partition. Just to clarify, message C (a record consumed from a different Kafka partition than A & B) can be processed in-between A & B. So the output Kafka topic could be produced with A => C => B.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Since A and C were in different partitions to begin with, I don't care in what order they're processed.

Comment: I also need to set `kafka.max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Comment: just to make sure I understand: to ensure ordering I need to: 1) repartition by the ordering key, then 2) order inside-partition, and then 3) send. Is it right?
Also, we cannot make any other transformation that will potentially trigger shuffling after 1) and 2) and before 3). Make sense?